# Need some tips with how to convert a hexadecimal color value to a rgb() one

Tags: javascript

I just started reading *Object-Oriented JavaScript* and am stuck on an exercise.

On page 91 it asks to write a function that converts a hex color into its RGB equivalent (eg "rgb(0,0,255)"). It requires that you pull in the full string including the '#'.

After reading through the two chapters he has spent on explaining data types, loops, conditions,and functions I don't know how to parse the hex value without cheating and using some sort of string function - something he hasn't even covered at this point.

Is there a way you can do this exercise using only the functions and methods he's demonstrated in the book?  He asks that javascript return **"rgb(0,255,0)"** if the following code is entered:

```
var a = getRGB("#00FF00");
a;
```

I'm assuming you would need to break up the hex value into an array for the r,g and b values using a loop and then recombine them into the string.  If possible, please don't give me the entire solution but any helpful hints would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: no, technically he never covered it in the material so I don't know why/how a new programmer would know to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you said without any string methods. Here is how to do the first part with only `Array` methods...

- Use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to turn the string into an array.
- Swap the `substr()` calls with [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

However, in the Real World, you can use [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to extract portions of a string. The first argument is the offset, the second is the number of characters to extract.

You can then use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to change the base of the number. You simply pass in the number (as a string) as the first argument, and the base as the second. I chose the radix of `16` as these are hexadecimal numbers.

You can then concatenate the return values with `rgb(x,x,x)` string portion and you are good to go :)

You can mouseover below to see the code (if you get stuck). BTW, does anyone know how to make a block level code spoiler?

> var getRGB = function(rgb) {
>         var r = rgb.substr(1, 2),
>             g = rgb.substr(3, 2),
>             b = rgb.substr(5, 2);
>
>         return 'rgb(' + parseInt(r, 16) + ',' + parseInt(g, 16) + ',' + parseInt(b, 16) + ')';
>     }

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/4b5mZ/http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/4b5mZ/).

Once you have figured this out, the next step may be to allow the function to accept the *short form* of RGB that browsers allow, i.e. your example `#00FF00` could be passed as `#0F0`.

Some tips...

- Check the string length first with `rgb.length`.
- Alter your `substr()` calls dependent on the length.
- Build the strings you pass to `parseInt()` so `F` becomes `FF`.

Comment: Just curious, will hex always be a 2 digit number?

Comment: @Chris It may be in short form, but I haven't allowed for this in the code.

Comment: It will, with 'digits' meaning 0-F (16 values possible)

Comment: @Alex - Is it only possible through sub strings? I'm bummed if that's the case because the book should take the skills you've learned in the previous chapter and build on them not presume you will find the functions elsewhere.

Comment: @boody See the first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks Alex and everyone else who contributed. I think this solution is pretty easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Get the input string and replace the # with nothing, then parse it to an integer using parseInt() and send 16 as the numeric base, now you have a long integer where the first 8 bits are the blue value, the bits from 9 to 16 are the green value and the bits from 17 to 24 are the red value. Use bit shifting and masking to pull them out. Put it all into a string like "rgb(r,g,b)", congrats, your done.

```
function parseRGB(Hex)
{
    var Word = parseInt(Hex.replace(/^#/, ""), 16);
    var R = Word >> 16 & 0xff;
    var G = Word >> 8 & 0xff;
    var B = Word & 0xff;

    return "rgb(" + R + ", " + G + ", " + B + ")";
}
var c = "#00ff00";
alert(parseRGB(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another 2-bit method, suitable for using input strings

```
function hextoRgb(hex){
    if(/^#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}$/.test(hex)){
        var c= '0x'+hex.substring(1);
        c= [(c>> 16)&255, (c>> 8)&255, c&255];
        return 'rgb('+c.join(',')+')';
    }
    throw 'bad hex '+hex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't give myself credit for answering the question but I thought I would share the result of emailing the author (I guess you can do that these days!!!).  He provided me a tip and here is what I came up with which works as he asked it to:

```
function getRGB(x){
var a =[];
a[0] = parseInt(x[1] + x[2],16);
a[1] = parseInt(x[3] + x[4],16);
a[2] = parseInt(x[5] + x[6],16);
a = "rgb(" + a[0] + "," + a[1] + "," + a[2] + ")";   
return a;
```

}

var a = getRGB("#00FF00");
a;